# Twilio number forward to virtual phone system

Tags: twilio

I have a local twilio number that I send/receive SMS with. I also want to allow people to call that number but I don't want to build a whole voice system for it. Seems like I should be able to have calls to the twilio number go to a virtual phone system like Grasshopper or something like that.

Someone else had a similar question - [Grasshopper Voice + Twilio Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443016/grasshopper-voice-twilio-text)

The answer given was really good, except that it suggests sending SMS from an 800 number whereas I want the SMS to come from a local number.

I have an existing twilio and grasshopper account but I can easily make another acccount for either.

I tried just forwarding incoming calls to my grasshopper number using the `<Dial>` XML from twilio, but it doesn't work. I get a dialup type sound on the other line, as if I called a fax machine.

I don't need a complicated voice system, I just want the ability to have voicemail and a couple extensions like Grasshopper has. I also don't mind using a different service other than grasshopper.

Any thoughts? Greatly appreciated any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Twimlets`](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/) sound perfect for your use case. You can chain together the [forwarding twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/forward/) and the [voicemail twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/voicemail) to achieve your desired functionality. There's a video guide on setting up such a system [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/06/build-your-own-google-voice-using-twilio-twimlets.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

With Twilio functions this is easier now. You don't have to host anything anywhere and you can have multiple extensions. Just create a new Function linked to Incoming Voice Call events, then set your provisioned number to call that Function when a new call arrives. Here's a working example you can modify to fit your preferences. It also has basic business hours (but doesn't support daylight saving).

https://gist.github.com/ChristopherThorpe/521bfdbd903ac7628ac01f8bb1d651a5